# Trigger step function through React UI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I have utility where I need to trigger a step function in aws through a button(that button is on react UI).

Is there any direct way(other that API gateway) to make the UI to backend connection for triggering that step function on clicking the button on UI.

Any code pointers would be helpful..

Comment: why not using Step Functions API StartExecution? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html
Obviously, you need proper permission to make that call.

Comment: @AnthonyB. (I know till the IAM role creation) I need to make IAM role for step function in the same aws account where the step function is present and attach a policy to it. 
Then how I would access frontend or I would say how we can connect that IAM with frontend.. can you please provide some more info on it .

Comment: your StepFunction needs an IAM role with permissions, like writing logs into cloudwatch or trace in Xray. Now, in order to call the StartExecution API for StepFunction, you need a role that can be attached to the user logged in into your app.

Comment: Your UI will need to get temporary credentials that has permissions to Start the Step Function and then make the API call to StartExecution with these temporary credentials